# WIX: forcing install subdirectory

Tags: installation, wix

I have a directory structure in the wxs file like usual:

```
<Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
   <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="$(var.ProductName)">
```

But I am wondering is there a way to force the INSTALLFOLDER to always end in the same directory, but still display correctly on the install folder edit dialog.

So if I select `C:\` as the install folder, I want it still to install to: `C:\{ProductName}\..`

I know I can do the following:

```
<Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="$(var.ProgramFiles)">
        <Directory Id="Observador" Name="$(var.ProductName)">
```

but then the EditText box in InstallDirDlg displays `C:\Program Files\` instead of `C:\Program Files\{ProductName}`

Comment: I can think of ways of doing it, but why waste your time?  Why not just let the user browse and put it where they want to?

Comment: @ChristopherPainter, +1! It would piss me off if I choose the installation folder, but the program ends up in another... Mark, don't complicate the things - Windows Installer is quite complex itself :)

Comment: I agree with both Christopher and Yan. I see no reason in letting users change the installation directory where they don't have complete control after all. In such case, it's wiser to not let users change the directory at all.

Comment: Fair enough, I was just seeing if it was possible.